# Searching for a function

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence

I'm searching for a funcion with this values:
f(0)=0
f(1)=1
f(2)=3/2
f(3)=7/4
...
lim from x to infinity: f(x) = 2

I *don't want* the recursive way to define f.

Comment: Firstly is the domian $\mathbb { N } $?  And what do you mean by recursive?

Comment: Looks like the function you're looking for would be something like $ f(x) = \frac{2^x - 1}{2^{x-1}} $. Of course, there are infinitely many other such functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(n)=\frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}$$

Answer (score 2):

How about:

$$f(x)=\frac{2^x-1}{2^{x-1}}$$

?